# How do I do many pull requests to a project on Github and keep my master updated at the same time while waiting for reviews?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm contributing to a project and there are a bunch of issues I'd like to solve.
So I should do a PR per issue. For this it's not a problem: I just make a branch per each issue, work on each issue separately, and then do a PR from each different branch.

But on top of this, I'd like to keep my master updated with all the changes I've done as this is also the version I'm personally using on my projects.

How do I do this?

If I merge a feature back into master, then new branches (and other PRs) will still contain the commits from those changes.

Same if I make new feature branches using previous branches as base, all new PRs will contain also commits from the previous PR if those are still being reviewed.

One possible solution could be to always work on master (or dev) and then when I need to create a PR I create a new branch starting from upstram/master and then I cherry-pick the commits I want into the PR.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

As you have already reasoned out, there is no nice way to deal with having many extant feature branches when your current/future work depends on changes contained within those branches.  The nice way to handle this is to fix the problem of your ignored feature branch pull requests.  You should communicate to your peers that they need to review more quickly.

If this *can't* happen, then one alternative to also eliminate your stale feature branch problem is to simply extend the feature and keep working in that branch.

Comment: Well... it's a contribution to a public project, so not much saying on what the maintainer do. They are not always fast approving PRs. And cannot extend the PR with other features as I need one PR per issue

Comment: What if I always work on master (or dev) and then when I need to create a PR I create a new branch starting from upstram/master and then I cherry-pick the commits I want into the PR?

Comment: @CodeClimber This is a very clever idea, but it still has a problem: You don't know in which order the reviewers will complete the pull requests.  Hence, things may go in out of order.

Comment: One PR could be accepted and one rejected.  So I already took this into account and all PRs are atomic.
Indeed it won't work if one PR depends on another

Comment: If the individual PRs are really atomic, then yes your idea might work.  You could maintain an alternate version of `master`, rebasing as you go along, and then send off pull requests for certain chunks of the commits which you have on top of the remote `master`.  Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you PR from a branch and keep working on it, code gets added to that branch. The person that accepts it can accept the lot or cherry-pick using, well, `git cherry-pick`. So best thing is to keep all your changes in a single branch. Even if it's not reviewed immediately, incorporating it to master branch will be simpler and smoother that way.

Comment: It's contributions to a OSS project on github... don't want to add more work that needed to the already busy maintainer. Not nice for him to see a PR with lots of unrelated commits

Comment: Create a branch for every independent feature that you want added, is my point.